# Magento CSS file weird behaviour

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have made some changes in a CSS file and uploaded it again via FTP. I have cleared the cache and my browser cache.

When I visit:

```
http://www.mystore.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/webandpeople/onepagecheckout/onepagecheckout.css
```

The old CSS file is shown.

But if I visit:

```
http://www.mystore.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/webandpeople/onepagecheckout/onepagecheckout
```

I get the new version, which I would also expect to be shown when having `.css`. It is a multi site magento v. 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear/flush the varnish cache?

Comment: I have noticed 3 cache folders in var. Named cache, cache1, cache2 there are 3 domains.

Comment: I notice it is a cache problem on 1 domain it is updated, but an another domain it has not.